# Editing Generator in PSSE from python script

Tags: python, psse

Im new in python programming for PSS/E simulation software. I want to know how can i modify the values of Pgen Qgen Pmax Qmax not from machine data record user interface but from the python script and then make a dynamic simulation.
Thanks in advance
Ersi Ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```
psspy.machine_chng_2(101,r"""1""",[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[ 100.0,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f])
```

That is to change Pgen of machine located at bus 101